# What is the rule when pronouncing words that start with G?

Tags: prononciation

I read a lot of French and constantly find myself not knowing how to pronounce words that start with G, e.g.:

- *gérer*
- *gants*

That is, when is it a hard G as in *girl*, and when is it a soft G (something like *jerry*)?

Is there a simple rule I can follow to know how to pronounce French words that start with G?

Comment: This alternation is not limited to French words *starting* with G...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We can separate 2 sorts of vowels:

- "a", "o", "u" are the strong vowels
- "e", "i", "y" are the weak vowels

- g + a **strong vowel (a,o,u)** will be pronounced as a **g like in girl**
- g + a **weak vowel (e,i,y)** will be pronounced as a **j like in jerry**

You have the same rule for the pronunciation of "c":

- c + a **strong vowel (a,o,u)** will be pronounced as a **c like in car**
- c + a **weak vowel (e,i,y)** will be pronounced as an **s like in soap**

Also, a "ç" will be pronounced as an **s like in soap** no matter of which letter is following. (thanks @jv42)

Comment: Glad your answer came before I finished mine, I would have forgotten "y".

Comment: About the 'c' case, you could add the 'c cédile' or 'ç', which allows for 'c' + strong vowel to be pronounced like 's'.

Comment: @jv42 : 'cédille' with 2 *l*

Comment: @Shikiryu, oops, thanks for correcting.

Comment: and the ç can only be found before *a*, *o* or *u*.

Comment: Some words have an "e" inserted to stop the "g" from changing its sound, e.g. "nous mangeons" from "manger". Normally in "-er" verbs the "e" is dropped when adding "-ons".

Comment: The French sound for g in ge/gi/gy is closer to the pronunciation of s in pleasure than the j in jerry (which would definitely sound foreign). What about the gue/gui orthography?

Answer (score 11):

The pronunciation of `g` is determined solely by the following letter (apart from a few recent imports). This is unrelated to `g` being the first letter of the word.

`G` followed by `e`,`i` or `y` is a “soft G”, i.e. the [[ʒ]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_%CA%92) sound (a [voiced palato-alveolar sibilant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_palato-alveolar_sibilant)). This sound is rarely present in English: words like “jerry” have a /dʒ/ sound. The French soft `g`, which is also the pronunciation of the letter `j`, is the pronunciation of `s` in English words like *vision* or *Asia*.

`G` followed by `a`, `o`, `u` or a consonant, or `g` at the end of a word (when it's not silent), is a “hard G”, i.e. the [[g]](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/API_%C9%A1) sound (a [voiced velar plosive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_velar_plosive)), i.e. the `g` in “girl”.

When a hard G sound is needed before `e`, `i` or `y`, French spelling adds a silent `u`: the `u` modifies the pronunciation of the `g` but does not introduce a vowel sound. Example: *ligue* (a league), pronounced `[lig]` (rhyming with “big” in English). Conversely, -ge- can be used before `a`, `o` or `u` to force a soft G; etymology dictates whether the spelling is `-ge-` or `-j-`.

The same distinction exists for `c`, which is a soft C ([s] sound) before `e`, `i` or `y`, and a hard C ([k] sound) everywhere else. (Incidentally, English has the same rule for C.) There are a few words where `-cu-` is used to transcribe a [k] sound (e.g. *écueil* (reef): [ekœj]), but usually `-qu-` is used instead. A [cedilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla) on a `c` (i.e. `ç`) forces the soft sound.

Answer (score -1):

The pronunciation changes when there is an 'e' or 'a' right after it.

So in *gérer* it is a soft 'g'.

Where as in *gants* it is a hard 'g',